# Only Owner (creator) can edit/delete Entry expressJS

Tags: express, authentication

How can I write a middleware to approve only owner of a entry to edit/ delete/ ?

I try to search each entry (in each entry have the userId), then compare UserId of current user to userId in entry.
But it's not the good way

Answer (score 0):

To be able to validate this, you need to know two tings:

- whos the current user
- whos the owner of the element

From what I can deduce of your question, you have the userId, and I'm presupposing it's on the request.

Now, what about the entry. The entry you wish to delete is most likely in the database, so you would have to query the database to find the element and see if the owner is  the current user. Remember to never trust anything that comes from a REST client

Here is an outline of a middleware that can do this for you:

```
const validateOwner = (req, res, next) => {
  const entryId = req.params.entryId || req.body.entryId;
  if (entryId === undefined) {
    return res.status(400).send('missing entryid);
  }
  const userId = req.user.userId;

  Database.findEntryWithId(entryId).then(entry => {
    if (entry.ownerId === userId) {
      next();
    } else {
      return res.status(403).send('Forbidden Action');
    }
  }).catch(() => {
    return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  };
};
```

**Using the middleware for delete**

```
app.delete('/api/entries/:entryId', validateOwner, (req, res) => {
  //Delete logic
  res.send('Element was deleted');
});
```

**Using the middleware for update**

```
app.put('/api/entries/', validateOwner, (req, res) => {
  //Delete logic
  res.send('Element was deleted');
});
```

Because the user can change the entryId in the client and send it back to the server, we have to validate the entryId from the database, and not trust the id in the body.